# Playing multiple songs independently on 8 channels

Tags: windows, audio

How can I play multiple song files, each one in a specific channel on a usb 7.1 sound card?
Computer specs are:
4gb ram
Windows 2003 Server
Proc Intel Xeon x3430

It have no internal sound card, and I can't install one.

The idea is to have 8 playlists, where each one will play on its own channel on the sound card.

Comment: What card?  Many of those cards are not actually true 8-channel.  Also, the subwoofer outputs of those cards are typically very poor quality, so it may not be usable depending on your needs.  It's best to get a proper professional 8-channel sound interface for this sort of thing, and either use Windows Core Audio or ASIO to interface.